# Should annotations be included in code coverage?

Tags: java, unit-testing, annotations, code-coverage

Well the questions is fairly self-explanatory.

How do various (java) code coverage tools treat annotations? Are they considered as code and included in coverage reports? They are not "executable" exactly, so I'm a bit confused about how they would be treated.

PS: Btw I've googled it already, there isn't much on this topic!

Comment: So what is that you want to be reviewed in Annotation?

Comment: Nothing! I'm referring to whether a line of "annotation" is considered as a line of code with regards to code coverage measurements, and if so how do you get coverage for it when it is not strictly executable. For example JSR validation annotations are only used by the validator when dealing with the bean, not the bean itself (and inherently it's own unit test).

Comment: There is no need to generate coverage for annotations as it is just meta data.

Comment: @Pangea the question is not if annotations SHOULD be included in relative line coverage, it is if they ARE included by coverage tools. I agree with you in point, but read the question more clearly.

Comment: @AshkanAryan - it's not that hard to test. Create a class and a test for it. Run it through some coverage tool with and without a bunch of annotations and see if you get different coverage information.

Comment: I kinda agree with the points made. But if they are not covered, how do we know if they are present? It's a bit of a gray area in my mind. I know the actual code behind each annotation would have it's own unit test and also would possibly be hit by integration tests. But it being part of what defines behaviour of the class... how do we have a measure of comfort that the bean is configured properly with them and their presence is tested?

Comment: The only way to test that is to do something with them.  Annotations have no semantic meaning on their own -- they only have meaning when you do something with them.  So test that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that Annotations are meta-data, so they are not part of the code that can be covered. There's a bit more to think about though.
What *should* be included in code coverage and what *could* be included can be quite different, depending on the technology you use.

Most coverage tools (I know cobertura and ECLEmma) never really look at the source code, they look at the bytecode. Not every line of something that you see in your source file corresponds to anything in the executable portions of .class file.

Annotations make this even more complicated, because some annotations are only meta-data in the source code, some are compiled and kept in the bytecode. For sure, annotations that are just meta-data should not be considered code, so they shouldn't be included in coverage info. Even annotations that are kept in the binaries should not directly be considered code to cover. Something like

```
@MyAnnotation
class MyClass ...
```

is not executable. The annotation placed there has no executable aspect. So it can't be covered. Up to here, this is pretty certain.

From here on, I'm speculating a bit. Annotations can contain data fields that can be queried. I don't know whether the compiler generates getter methods for that (which in principle is code that could be covered), or if they are public fields that are read directly by callers.